# can I launch a program from windows7 task manager as the user "system"?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-server-2008, windows-task-scheduler

I have tried to launch several installers as the user system, from task manager.  All attempts have failed.  if I use the local admin, or domain admin I can launch the installer from task manager.  I have tried windows 7 sp1 and windows server 2008 RC2 SP1.

was this ever possible ?

Comment: What are you trying to do that makes you think launching a process as System is the solution. There are ways to do it, [but it would be a lot better to solve your real problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Why can't you use the Administrator account if it works?

Answer (score 0):

You can run commands under the local system account with [Psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx)

Be careful.